# how to find substrings in main string using python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string,

```
"(sorry patricia if the fbi comes)_EN (to)_BN (your)_EN (new home)_BN (you bought in cash)_EN (... #)_UN (wrongnumber)_EN".
```

I want to find the substrings that start with `"("` and end with `")_EN"`. So the result would be like:

```
sorry patricia if the fbi comes

your

you bought in cash

wrongnumber
```

I am very new to python so kindly help me with this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, refer this to know how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `\(([^)]*)\)_EN` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OKHmtt/1/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> s="(sorry patricia if the fbi comes)_EN (to)_BN (your)_EN (new home)_BN (you bought in cash)_EN (... #)_UN (wrongnumber)_EN"
>>> print('\n'.join(re.findall(r'\(([^)]*)\)_EN',s)))
sorry patricia if the fbi comes
your
you bought in cash
wrongnumber
```

Here is a [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OKHmtt/1/) and explanation of that regex.

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.endwith ("the string to match")` and `str.startswith("the string to match')`.
Check out here https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_endswith.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_startswith.asp .
Hope it helps you ,and please edit your question properly ,thanks.